# Change an element of global vector in a function

Tags: r, global-variables, assign

I have a vector in global environment and I want to create a function that modifies only one element of that vector. The problem is that the vector is too large and standard methods take too long to compute. See functions I already have, both of them are too slow.

```
x <- rep(0, 1e8)
f1 <- function(n,a) {
  x <- x      # loads the vector to current environment
  x[n] <- a   # changes the position in current environment
  x <<- x     # saves the vector to global environment
}
f2 <- function(n,a) {
  x[n] <<- a  # changes the vector element in global environment
}

system.time(f1(1,1))   # 0.34
system.time(f2(2,1))   # 0.30
system.time(x[3] <- 1) # 0.00
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
assign('x[4]', 1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the third command?

Comment: @Jimbou I need to have the command inside of a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, you can address this with `data.table` package as it manipulates object by reference.

For instance:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(x=rep(0, 1e8))

f3 <- function(n,a){ 
  data[n,x:=a]
  return(TRUE)  
}

system.time(f3(2,1))   # 0
print(data)
x
1: 0
2: 1
3: 0
4: 0
...
```

You can retrieve `x` as vector at any time with `data[["x"]]`

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks